# Need logic about developing a school schedule system in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a dynamic class schedule system in php mysql.
I have a dynamically generated form inside a table like this.

http://s9.postimg.org/v5vu5624v/form_help.jpg

After completing the form php will take those form data and store 
it in database. But this is a complex task. Because I have to track
day name , period number with subject name. For example

user is entering the subject name in period 1 and day is Saturday.
after submitting the form php will store period name , day name 
and subject name.

I am tracking this because I have to display user input data 
exact same position. For example user has entered subject name in period 1 and day 
is Saturday. So php will retrieve data from database and display this
in period 1 and Saturday.

If user input single data then its an easy process. But as it is a class schedule so 
data wont be single . There will be multiple data.

Now my question is how can I do that. How could I track the subject name
in which day and which period?

BTW, I am sending this form to another php page as post method, and that page will handle this task.

Comment: This is quite a big task and you need to break it down into steps and plan how you will store this data, retrieve and display it. You would of course need to store also the `day` and `period` part into the DB. What do you need right now, anyway? This is a long procedure and I doubt anyone will actually draw up a database schema for your system now.

Comment: It sounds like you are using an html form to construct a multi-dimensional array in php, and then inserting that into a MySQL database. This is standard stuff and there are hundreds of tutorials on this topic.

Comment: My first aim is to send data to another php page. But I have to send extra data for tracking, to know which subject is coming from which period and which day. 

To do that I have added a hidden field.There some predefined data such as day and period.Also there is a subject which user types in subject textbox (its done by javascript). Finally hidden field data looks like this "Saturday_Math_1". Saturday is day name , Math is subject name and 1 is period name. Now I will send the hidden field data to another php file. 
Please inform me ,will this trick work?